# JavaScript - "Combining" two similar arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mapreduce

Let's say I have the following two arrays:

```
let arr1 = [ { id: "1234567890", name: "Someone", other: "unneeded", props: 123 } ... ];
let arr2 = [ { id: "1234567890", points: 100, other: "unneeded", props: 456 } ... ];
```

I need to combine these based on  the name and points by id which looks like:

```
[ { id: "1234567890", name: "Someone", points: 100 } ... ]
```

One option would be to map them like so:

```
let final = arr1.map(u => ({
    id: u.id,
    name: u.name,
    points: arr2.find(uu => uu.id === u.id)
}));
```

However, this is inefficient for larger arrays (thousands of entries), since `find()` iterates through the array each time. I'm trying to make this more efficient. I read over [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), but that doesn't seem like the answer (unless I'm wrong). How can I do this?

Comment: What is the logic you're using for combination here?

Comment: @Ashish as shown in the example for the final array, I want to "merge" the `name` and `points` by `id`

Comment: Is id always an integer?

Comment: @TommiTuura edited, was supposed to be a string, but yes, itll always be a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from the objects of the second array so that you can access the corresponding object directly by id in constant time:

```js
let arr1 = [
  {id: 1234567890, name: "Someone", other: "unneeded", props: 123},
  {id: 1234567891, name: "Someone1", other: "unneeded1", props: 124},
  {id: 1234567892, name: "Someone2", other: "unneeded2", props: 125}
];
let arr2 = [
  {id: 1234567890, points: 100, other: "unneeded", props: 456},
  {id: 1234567891, points: 101, other: "unneeded", props: 457},
  {id: 1234567892, points: 102, other: "unneeded", props: 458}
];

let arr2Map = arr2.reduce((a, c) => {
  a.set(c.id, c);
  return a;
}, new Map());

let final = arr1.map(({id, name, points}) => 
  ({id, name, points: arr2Map.get(id).points || points}));

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could try is [Webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). If you haven't used them before, they can run script in a separate thread, essentially allowing you to use multiple cores in order to process something. They are great for parallelizable tasks, meaning tasks that can broken up without any disruption. They would fit your use case pretty well since you are just doing a big map on your data.

Before going down this path though you should be forewarned that there is some overhead with webworkers. In order to get data into a webworker you have to serialize it into the thread and then deserialize it when it returns. However, if you split up your tasks into separate works and have them operating in parallel you should be able to mitigate some of that.

```
// app.js
let largeArray = []; // contains the large amount of arrays to map
let outputArray = []; 
while(largeArray.length){
    let worker = new Worker('/path/to/worker/script.js');
    worker.postMessage({
        chunk: largeArray.splice(0,1000)
    });
    worker.onmessage = evt => {
        let data = evt.data;
        outputArray = outputArray.concat(data);
        worker.terminate();
    }
}
```

Separately have a worker script, maybe similar to this one available to be referenced.

```
// workerScript.js
self.onmessage = ({data: {chunk}}) => {
    let final = chunk.map(u => ({
        id: u.id,
        name: u.name,
        points: arr2.find(uu => uu.id === u.id)
    }));
    self.postMessage(final);
}
```

You might ask about the serializing, and it's something that happens automatically. Webworkers have their own global scope, and as a result of serializing you can send Objects, Arrays, and primitives. All of this can be serialized. Objects with custom properties and classes will throw errors though. Behind the scenes it's basically taking your data and doing `JSON.stringify({{your data}})` and then within the webworker data becomes the result of `JSON.parse({{serialized data}})`.

Because this work is occurring in separate threads you won't see any blocking on the main thread where your app is running. If you are trying to process too much at once though, the serializing will be noticeable as it's blocking until completion.